# Document library browser hanging

Tags: document-library, archive

I work with a SharePoint site used as archive. It has a couple of document libraries used as archive. I'm in the middle of longer process of moving large number of items from one list into this archive document-library (using a workflow) and has done this in batches over a few hundred items at a time, over a few days, but today after doing another batch of items, my browser starts hanging after a few seconds when I attempt to open the archive library.

Other libraries on the same site works fine, except this one. It now contains some 9000 items, but I don't think that should be an issue, and certainly not that suddenly. Basically the page responds really really sluggish and a few seconds after opening it, it stops responding to input and sometimes turns to a white page (stops rendering?)

I tried opening it while having Google Chrome task manager open and the process with the page in, starts consuming a good 25% CPU steadily with the total memory usage slowly but steadily increasing bit by bit. reminiscent of memory leak.

I can't think of any changes done to the library today besides transferring some more items like I have done several times before without problems. the Drop-off library for the archive site is empty indicating that all received items have been sorted correctly. There are no workflows associated with the archive doc-library.

Any suggestions what could cause this, and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The default view was set to display 1200 items (Must have been altered by someone as the default is 30)
I created a new view in SharePoint Designer, made it default and then changed the other one back to 30 items at a time, which solved the issue.